# How do you hide the panels in 12.04 2d?

Tags: panel, mythbuntu, fullscreen

I run mythbuntu, and the panels in 2d apparently cannot be hidden?

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a small [GUI tool](http://marianochavero.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/small-desktop-configuration-tool-for-ubuntu-unity-2d-12-04-lts/) that did what you want and little more

Answer (score 0):

Being that you mention 2D, you aren't running Mythbuntu, you are running Unity. What you need to do is install CCSM (Compiz config settings manager) and enable legacy mode.